# url aliasing for profile names in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I want to write the profile names like `www.example.com/profilename`

For this I thought of redirecting every name that wasn't a `controller` to my profile `controller`.
I used the following code

```
$route['(![abc])'] = "profile/$1";
```

But this does not seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

You must understand that with this kind of routing almost everything will go to your profile controller.
What you can do is the following steps. The first thing you have to do is route everything to the profile controller and then reset some routes to your other controllers. Like this:

```
*/
Route to profile if there only characters in the request. 
When it has special characters in it will be passed.
*/
$route['([a-z]+)/(:any)'] = 'profile/?profile=$1';

// Now make sure other controllers can be called too
$route['other/(:any)'] = 'other/$1';

// And another controller.. etc.
$route['etc/(:any)'] = 'etc/$1';
```

I don't exactly know what you are making, but it's a bit a bad way to use routes. Only if you are making like a community centered or social media platform. I certainly understand it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have to explicitly create a rule to route for your controllers and redirect everything else to profile.

```
$controllers = array('profile','signup','...');

foreach($controllers as $controller) {
    $route[$controller] = $controller."/index";
    $route[$controller."/(:any)"] = $controller."/$1";
}

$route['(:any)'] = "profile/$1";
```